# Python "all" function with conditional generator expression returning True. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Can anyone help me understand why the following Python script returns `True`?

```
x = ''
y = all(i == ' ' for i in x)
print(y)
```

I imagine it's something to do with `x` being a zero-length entity, but cannot fully comprehend.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`all()` always returns `True` *unless* there is an element in the sequence that is `False`.

Your loop produces 0 items, so `True` is returned.

This is [documented](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> Return `True` if all elements of the *iterable* are true (**or if the iterable is empty**).

Emphasis mine.

Similarly, [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) will always return `False`, *unless* an element in the sequence is `True`, so for empty sequences, `any()` returns the default:

```
>>> any(True for _ in '')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) states, what `all` does is:

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).