# How can I check if a list of nodes have already been included in a list within a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, element

I have the following list: `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` which contains 3 lists, each being a list of nodes of a graph.

I am also given a tuple of nodes `z = ([1,2], [4,9])`. Now, I will like to check if either of the lists in `z` has been included in a list in `a`. For example, `[1,2]` is in `[1,2,3]`, in `a`, **but** `[4,9]` is not in `[4,5,6]`, although there is an overlapping node.

**Remark:** To clarify, I am also checking for sub-list of a list, or whether every item in a list is in another list. For example, I consider [1,3] to be "in" [1,2,3].

How can I do this? I tried implementing something similar found at [Python 3 How to check if a value is already in a list in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503821/python-3-how-to-check-if-a-value-is-already-in-a-list-in-a-list), but I have reached a mental deadlock..

Some insight on this issue will be great!

Comment: Rule of thumb, when you are checking whether something already exists, hashmap is probably your go to.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar Thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately I am a beginner to Python and it will be probably take quite a while for me to 'master' hashmapping.. :/

Comment: Try looking into sets.

Comment: Are you looking to check for *sub-list* of a list, or simply if every item in a list is in another list? That is, do you consider `[1,3]` to be "in" `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: @blhsing Yes I am. I stated it in my example above. Thanks for the question though. I will add in your remarks to make it clearer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` and `all`:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
z = ([1,2], [4,9])
results = [i for i in z if any(all(c in b for c in i) for b in a)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: I didn't even know these keywords existed :o

Comment: Thanks @Ajax1234! Just curious what does the all() operator do?

Comment: @T.Woody https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257821/python-all-function-with-conditional-generator-expression-returning-true-why

Comment: @T.Woody note: `any` and `all` are not keywords but builtins (`for` and `in` are keywords). @Stoner `all()` ensures all conditions are `True`, `any()` ensures at least one condition is `True`.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the clarifications. I'll accept this answer as it is easier for me to comprehend at my level of mastery of Python! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set`s to compare if the nodes appear in `a`, `<=` operator for sets is equivalent to `issubset()`.
`itertools` module provides some useful functions, `itertools.product()` is equivalent to nested `for` loops.
E.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
[m for m, n in it.product(z, a) if set(m) <= set(n)]

Out[]:
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer too! I didn't know sets can be used this way

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

z = ([1,2], [4,9])

for z_ in z:
    for a_ in a:
        if set(z_).issubset(a_):
            print(z_)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just to clarify, is `issubset()` built-in or do I have to import a package?

Comment: `issubset()` is a method on the standard `set` type, no imports necessary.

Comment: @Stoner you do not need to import, for your reference https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only looking to test the sub-lists as if they were subsets, you can convert the sub-lists to sets and then use `set.issubset()` for the test:

```
s = map(set, a)
print([l for l in z for i in s if set(l).issubset(i)])
```

This outputs:

```
[[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just curious, how does map actually work?

Comment: Did you mean `a = map(set, a)` because currently `s = map(set, a)` is not being used, you are redefining `s` in the comprehension and still using `a`. Note: it works because `issubset()` will take any iterable (this doesn't happen with `<=` set operator).

Comment: @AChampion Thanks. My bad. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @Stoner The `map` function iterates through the list specified by the second argument and passes each item in the list to the function specified by the first argument, so `map(set, a)` converts `a` from a list of lists to a sequence of sets. Please refer to [`map`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` is your friend (no installation builtin python module):

```
from itertools import product
print([i for i in z if any(tuple(i) in list(product(l,[len(i)])) for l in a)])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2]]
```